# RStudio server Error: Incorrect or invalid username/password

Tags: r, linux, debian, rstudio-server, pam

I installed the RStudio Server on my Debian 8 VPS. I get the "Error: Incorrect or invalid username/password" message when I try to log in R Studio's web panel, using VPS's root id (root) and password. It seems that it is related to the PAM authentication, though I don't know how the pam.d profiles are changed accordingly.

How can I solve this issue?